# Exception after upgrade to Creator Edition

Tags: c#, windows-10, reportviewer

The following line of code worked fine up to yesterday.

```
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters().Count
```

My PC updated overnight to the 'Creator Edition' of Windows 10, and now I get the exception shown below...

```
'ReportViewer1.ServerReport.GetParameters()' threw an exception of type 'System.Net.WebException'
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2146233079
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: {"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:80"}
    Message: "Unable to connect to the remote server"
    Response: null
    Source: "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms"
    StackTrace: "   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetSecureMethods()\r\n   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname)\r\n   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.SetConnectionSSLForMethod(String methodname)\r\n   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute[TReturn](RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 sql16Method, ProxyMethod`1 katmaiMethod, ProxyMethod`1 yukonMethod)\r\n   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.LoadReport(String Report, String HistoryID)\r\n   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.LoadReport(String report, String historyId)\r\n   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
\r\n   at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.GetParameters()"
    Status: ConnectFailure
    TargetSite: {System.String[] GetSecureMethods()}
```

Has anyone else seen this happen? Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that the report server itself is not running. So can you access the Report Server portal itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few re-boots, this started working.

Maybe the Reports system didn't re-start itself after the update...